# sql - min of 9 weeks max of 15 weeks average of 16 weeks

Tags: sql, ms-access, average

This is what I desire for my query

- average for 16 wks
- min 9 wks
- max 15 wks
- increasing month NOT alphabetic

[image]

And my query so far looks like 
[image]

My code is

```
TRANSFORM SUM(Detail.Quantity)
SELECT Detail.ItemCode
FROM Detail INNER JOIN Header ON Detail.SalesOrderNo = Header.SalesOrderNo
WHERE Header.OrderDate>=dateadd("m",-4,Date())
GROUP BY Detail.ItemCode
PIVOT MonthName(Month([Header.OrderDate]));
```

Thank you so much in advance!

And It'd be appreciated If anyone can answer why 'October' is showing as of 2/1/2017? while my code has `WHERE Header.OrderDate>=dateadd("m",-4,Date())`?

Comment: Four months ago from today is `10/1/2016`.

Comment: @Parfait true that! thank you!!! Could you please give your input on my other questions? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a join of two crosstab queries.

**CrossTab1** Query *(specify the column order in PIVOT clause)*

```
TRANSFORM SUM(Detail.Quantity)
SELECT Detail.ItemCode
FROM Detail INNER JOIN Header ON Detail.SalesOrderNo = Header.SalesOrderNo
WHERE Header.OrderDate>=dateadd("m",-4,Date())
GROUP BY Detail.ItemCode
PIVOT MonthName(Month([Header.OrderDate]))
  IN ('November', 'December', 'January', 'February');
```

**UnionAggQ** Query *(save as separate query)*

Next crosstab needs another query as the source, specifically a union query of aggregates by *ItemCode* with categorical *Metric* column:

```
SELECT Detail.ItemCode,
       'AVG 16 WEEKS' AS Metric,
       AVG(Detail.Quantity) AS AggDetailQty
FROM Detail INNER JOIN Header ON Detail.SalesOrderNo = Header.SalesOrderNo
WHERE Header.OrderDate >= DATEADD("ww",-16, Date())
GROUP BY Detail.ItemCode

UNION ALL

SELECT Detail.ItemCode,
       'MIN 9 WEEKS' AS Metric,
       MIN(Detail.Quantity) AS AggDetailQty 
FROM Detail INNER JOIN Header ON Detail.SalesOrderNo = Header.SalesOrderNo
WHERE Header.OrderDate >= DATEADD("ww",-9, Date())
GROUP BY Detail.ItemCode

UNION ALL

SELECT Detail.ItemCode,
       'MAX 15 WEEKS' AS Metric,
       MAX(Detail.Quantity) AS AggDetailQty
FROM Detail INNER JOIN Header ON Detail.SalesOrderNo = Header.SalesOrderNo
WHERE Header.OrderDate >= DATEADD("ww",-15, Date())
GROUP BY Detail.ItemCode
```

**Crosstab2** Query

```
TRANSFORM SUM(q.AggDetailQty)
SELECT q.ItemCode
FROM UnionAggQuery q
GROUP BY q.ItemCode
PIVOT q.Type IN ('AVG 16 WEEKS', 'MIN 9 WEEKS', 'MAX 15 WEEKS');
```

**Final** Query *(joining both crosstabs)*

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM CrossTab1 t1 
INNER JOIN CrossTab2 t2
ON t1.ItemCode = t2.ItemCode
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! You are amazing!!! Thanks for making my day :) Hope you have a good night!