# sql - need clarification "q.type" on crosstab/aggregates for average/min/max

Tags: sql, ms-access, crosstab, aggregates

It's a follow-up question for my previous question:[sql - min of 9 weeks max of 15 weeks average of 16 weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992912/sql-min-of-9-weeks-max-of-15-weeks-average-of-16-weeks/41993836#41993836)

I'm getting "Enter parameter value of `q.Type`" when I execute parfait's awesome answer.

Can someone explain why and how can I substitute/specify it?

I don't want to manually enter value all the time..

The below is his code answer:

**Crosstab2** Query

```
TRANSFORM SUM(q.AggDetailQty)
SELECT q.ItemCode
FROM UnionAggQuery q
GROUP BY q.ItemCode
PIVOT **q.Type** IN ('AVG 16 WEEKS', 'MIN 9 WEEKS', 'MAX 15 WEEKS');
```

**UnionAggQ** Query (joining both crosstabs)

Next crosstab needs another query as the source, specifically a union query of aggregates by ItemCode with categorical Metric column:

```
SELECT Detail.ItemCode,
       'AVG 16 WEEKS' AS Metric,
       AVG(Detail.Quantity) AS AggDetailQty
FROM Detail INNER JOIN Header ON Detail.SalesOrderNo = Header.SalesOrderNo
WHERE Header.OrderDate >= DATEADD("ww",-16, Date())
GROUP BY Detail.ItemCode

UNION ALL

SELECT Detail.ItemCode,
       'MIN 9 WEEKS' AS Metric,
       MIN(Detail.Quantity) AS AggDetailQty 
FROM Detail INNER JOIN Header ON Detail.SalesOrderNo = Header.SalesOrderNo
WHERE Header.OrderDate >= DATEADD("ww",-9, Date())
GROUP BY Detail.ItemCode

UNION ALL

SELECT Detail.ItemCode,
       'MAX 15 WEEKS' AS Metric,
       MAX(Detail.Quantity) AS AggDetailQty
FROM Detail INNER JOIN Header ON Detail.SalesOrderNo = Header.SalesOrderNo
WHERE Header.OrderDate >= DATEADD("ww",-15, Date())
GROUP BY Detail.ItemCode
```

**Final** Query

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM CrossTab1 t1 
INNER JOIN CrossTab2 t2
ON t1.ItemCode = t2.ItemCode
```

Comment: You should have `Type` column in UnionAggQ query, you don't have it. Also "Type" is a reserved word, use another name or eclose it in square brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
TRANSFORM SUM(q.AggDetailQty)
SELECT q.ItemCode
FROM UnionAggQuery q
GROUP BY q.ItemCode
PIVOT q.Metric IN ('AVG 16 WEEKS', 'MIN 9 WEEKS', 'MAX 15 WEEKS');
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for a great explanation :) It does work!! :) Thumbs up!!