# How not to use wildcards to avoid duplicate column names when joining

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, crosstab, aggregates

This is what I desire (ROQ & Trigger column can be blank)
[image]

[image]
This is **Query 3** that I want to Join to 
[image]

this **Join** query. 
[image]

I have tried but the column doesn't look like Query3.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
FROM CrossTab1 t1 
INNER JOIN CrossTab2 t2
ON t1.ItemCode = t2.ItemCode
INNER JOIN Query3 t3
ON t3.ItemCode = t3.ItemCode
```

My 2nd question: How can I delete `column t2.ItemCode` and `t3.ItemCode`? as the excel image above?

My other CrossTab code in detail: [sql - min of 9 weeks max of 15 weeks average of 16 weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992912/sql-min-of-9-weeks-max-of-15-weeks-average-of-16-weeks)

Thank you so so much in advance! I'll be as responsive as I can.

Comment: this question is very very dumb.  just list out each column name you want from each sub-query.  This is super basic use of alias names and wildcards in sql.

Comment: @hogan sorry for the dumb question

Comment: Your join to Query3 is not useful; `ON t3.ItemCode = t3.ItemCode`

Comment: @NicholasV. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got two upvotes so I will answer it...

You use field names instead of wild cards to specify the column names you actually want, like the code below

Since you **don't** give any detail about the field names of the different crosstabs I had to guess.  But use this as a template of how not to use wildcards when specifying column names.

```
SELECT t1.itemcode, t1.november, t1.december, t1.january, t2.[avg 16 weeks], t3.fieldnamefromt3
FROM CrossTab1 t1 
INNER JOIN CrossTab2 t2
ON t1.ItemCode = t2.ItemCode
INNER JOIN Query3 t3
ON t1.ItemCode = t3.ItemCode
```